# Service fabric Cluster provisioning fail after add secondary certificate through resource manager

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I was trying to swap the certificate of my service fabric cluster because the previous certificate was about to expire. Searching in the web i've found a way to add a secondary certificate to the cluster through azure resources manager.

So i added the certificate in my key vault and after that i added the certificate thumbprint to the cluster using the resources manager as a secondary certificate, till here everything is ok.

The problem happened when i tried to swap the two certificates through the azure portal, my cluster has entered in a state of cluster provisioning fail, and after that i can't make any changes to my cluster, it continue giving me the same error that the cluster have a pending change.

Bellow the description of the error:

> statusCode:BadRequest
>   serviceRequestId:dcb6f784-018e-4789-ac4d-4426bd68b66c
>   statusMessage:{"error":{"code":"PendingClusterUpgradeCannotBeInterrupted","message":"The
>   cluster is going through a an upgrade which cannot be
>   interrupted.","details":[]}}
>   responseBody:{"error":{"code":"PendingClusterUpgradeCannotBeInterrupted","message":"The
>   cluster is going through a an upgrade which cannot be
>   interrupted.","details":[]}}

Someone already had this problem before ?

Comment: Looks like you already have a running upgrade that needs to finish. If still stuck - open a support ticket through the Azure Portal.